# Print floating point values without leading zero

Tags: python, string-formatting

Trying to use a format specifier to print a float that will be less than 1 without the leading zero. I came up with a bit of a hack but I assume there is a way to just drop the leading zero in the format specifier. I couldn't find it in the docs.

Issue

```
>>> k = .1337
>>> print "%.4f" % k
'0.1337'
```

Hack

```
>>> print ("%.4f" % k) [1:]
'.1337'
```

Comment: What happens when your value is 0?

Comment: After studying [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), it seems that there is no canonical way to do this.

Comment: to clarify in the event of minus numbers like -0.1 do you want -.1000?

Comment: Yes, I think the most surprising thing is that this isn't possible with format specifiers alone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As much as I like cute regex tricks, I think a straightforward function is the best way to do this:

```
def formatFloat(fmt, val):
  ret = fmt % val
  if ret.startswith("0."):
    return ret[1:]
  if ret.startswith("-0."):
    return "-" + ret[2:]
  return ret

>>> formatFloat("%.4f", .2)
'.2000'
>>> formatFloat("%.4f", -.2)
'-.2000'
>>> formatFloat("%.4f", -100.2)
'-100.2000'
>>> formatFloat("%.4f", 100.2)
'100.2000'
```

This has the benefit of being easy to understand, partially because `startswith` is a simple string match rather than a regex.

Answer (score 34):

Here is another way:

```
>>> ("%.4f" % k).lstrip('0')
'.1337'
```

It is slightly more general than `[1:]` in that it also works with numbers >=1.

Neither method correctly handles negative numbers, however. The following is better in this respect:

```
>>> re.sub('0(?=[.])', '', ("%0.4f" % -k))
'-.1337'
```

Not particularly elegant, but right now I can't think of a better method.

Comment: The regex here will not work correctly on numbers with absolute value greater than ten that have a zero in the ones place. For example, 100.1337 becomes 10.1337.

Comment: I edited the regex to work with all real number inputs. Awaiting peer review. (`re.sub(r'^(-?)0(?=\.)', r'\1', ...)`)

Comment: @musicinmybrain You should write up your own answer with that regex

Comment: @musicinmybrain Editing another person's answer is for cleaning-up when something could be stated in a better way, not for fundamentally changing the answer. I agree with Rob Watts that you should create your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

One viable option which works without regex and with negative numbers greater than 10

```
k = -.1337
("%.4f" % k).replace("-0","-").lstrip("0")
```

Comment: `.` is a regex metacharacter.  Do you realize what would happen if `k` is `-100.1337`?

Comment: @devnull I accepted the answer 2 years ago. I actually didn't use his answer at the time because I didn't have to deal with negative numbers. Using replace wouldn't have any issues. I am not sure why you commented on this other than to get my attention to cancel my previous answer accept?

Comment: I didn't realize that this was an answer to your question.  Coming back to my comment, it'd produce `-10.1337` for the above example.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.lstrip()`, after using string formatting to convert to a string:

```
>>> k = .1827412
>>> print ("%.4f"%(k)).lstrip('0')
.1827
>>>
```

`.lstrip()` can be used to remove any of the leading characters of a string:

```
>>> k = 'bhello'
>>> print k.lstrip('b')
hello
>>> print k.lstrip('bhel')
o
>>> print k.lstrip('bel')
hello
>>>
```

[*From the docs*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lstrip):

> string.lstrip(s[, chars])
>
> Return a copy of the string with leading characters removed

Answer (score 5):

You may use the following `MyFloat` class instead of the builtin `float` class.

```
def _remove_leading_zero(value, string):
    if 1 > value > -1:
        string = string.replace('0', '', 1)
    return string


class MyFloat(float):
    def __str__(self):
        string = super().__str__()
        return _remove_leading_zero(self, string)

    def __format__(self, format_string):
        string = super().__format__(format_string)
        return _remove_leading_zero(self, string)
```

Using this class you'll have to use `str.format` function instead of the modulus operator (`%`) for formatting. Following are some examples:

```
>>> print(MyFloat(.4444))
.4444

>>> print(MyFloat(-.4444))
-.4444

>>> print('some text {:.3f} some more text',format(MyFloat(.4444)))
some text .444 some more text

>>> print('some text {:+.3f} some more text',format(MyFloat(.4444)))
some text +.444 some more text
```

If you also want to make the modulus operator (`%`) of `str` class to behave the same way then you'll have to override the `__mod__` method of `str` class by subclassing the class. But it won't be as easy as overriding the `__format__` method of `float` class, as in that case the formatted float number could be present at any position in the resultant string.

[Note: All the above code is written in Python3. **You'll also have to override `__unicode__` in Python2** and also have to change the `super` calls.]

P.S.: You may also override `__repr__` method similar to `__str__`, if you also want to change the [official string representation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) of `MyFloat`.

---

---

---

**Edit**: Actually you can add new syntax to format sting using `__format__` method. So, if you want to keep both behaviours, i.e. show leading zero when needed and don't show leading zero when not needed. You may create the `MyFloat` class as follows:

```
class MyFloat(float):
    def __format__(self, format_string):
        if format_string.endswith('z'):  # 'fz' is format sting for floats without leading the zero
            format_string = format_string[:-1]
            remove_leading_zero = True
        else:
            remove_leading_zero = False

        string = super(MyFloat, self).__format__(format_string)
        return _remove_leading_zero(self, string) if remove_leading_zero else string
        # `_remove_leading_zero` function is same as in the first example
```

And use this class as follows:

```
>>> print('some text {:.3f} some more text',format(MyFloat(.4444)))
some text 0.444 some more text
>>> print('some text {:.3fz} some more text',format(MyFloat(.4444)))
some text .444 some more text


>>> print('some text {:+.3f} some more text',format(MyFloat(.4444)))
some text +0.444 some more text
>>> print('some text {:+.3fz} some more text',format(MyFloat(.4444)))
some text +.444 some more text


>>> print('some text {:.3f} some more text',format(MyFloat(-.4444)))
some text -0.444 some more text
>>> print('some text {:.3fz} some more text',format(MyFloat(-.4444)))
some text -.444 some more text
```

Note that using 'fz' instead of 'f' removes the leading zero.

Also, the above code works in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Doesn't your `remove_leading_zeros` really `remove_all_zeros`. Seems clunky and incorrect.

Comment: @hobs, Please test the code before pointing out any issues, it works as expected. `string.replace('0', '', 1)` would only remove the first zero and `if 1 > value > -1` condition would make sure that it is only applied when the string is in form `0.<some digits>`.

Comment: Here's my (*unfair/unrealistic*) test case that produced an incorrect answer: `'.402'.replace('0', '', 1)` -> `.42` . Your code would work for all strings produced by the `__str__` on `float`s as currently defined, but your code is fragile (clunky). It's not idempotent. And it's not future-proof. `lstrip` is much more concise and robust (idempotent and future-proof). Your `replace` operation could not be applied more than once. And if your particular number type didn't stringify the way python builtin floats did, well...

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % k)
```

This is short, simple and I can't find a scenario for which it doesn't work.

Examples:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % 0)
'.0000'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % 0.1337)
'.1337'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % 1.337)
'1.3370'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % -0)
'.0000'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % -0.1337)
'-.1337'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % -1.337)
'-1.3370'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % 10.337)
'10.3370'
>>> re.sub("^(\-?)0\.", r'\1.', "%.4f" % -10.337)
'-10.3370'
```

**Edit**:
If you are only considering numbers > -10 and < 10 The following will work:

```
("%.4f", k).replace('0.', '.')
```

Comment: @JacobKrall damn you sir! edited to use ````re.sub```` and bracket matching works now

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather go for readable and simple than anything else: Let's handle the sign and the numerics independently. And a little in-line if statement never hurt anyone.

```
k = -.1337
"".join( ["-" if k < 0 else "", ("%.4f" % abs(k)).lstrip('0')] )
```

Comment: It's shorter if you concatenate `+` rather than using `join`. 'course, you'll need parenthesis around the sign logic.

Comment: I looked into using "+" for concatenation, because I've heard that it is not very pythonic. It turns out that using "".join() instead of + is about two orders of magnitude faster, and it also fits better into the style of python. That said, + is totally equivalent and probably easier to think up for almost any use case.

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised nobody suggested a more mathematical way to do it:

```
n = 0.123456789
'.%d' % (n*1e4)
```

Looks much nicer to me. :)

But interestingly yours is the fastest.

```
$ python -mtimeit '".%d" % (0.123456789*1e4)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.809 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit '("%.4f"%(0.123456789)).lstrip("0")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.209 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit '("%.4f"%(0.123456789))[1:]'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0723 usec per loop
```

Comment: Nice trick for numbers [0,1). It doesn't work outside of that range, though (not for negative numbers, or numbers >= 1.0.

Comment: This answer also does not round up.

Comment: I think you need '.%04d' to account for numbers close to 0. (e.g., .002)

Answer (score 2):

Since we're only considering > -1 to < 1 then the following edit will work.

```
import re
re.sub(r"0+\.", ".", %0.4f" % k)
```

This will maintain the sign, only removing the digit to the left of the decimal.

Comment: The OP only wants to trim digits left of the decimal point when the number is less than 1 and more than -1 eg 0.1 -> .1000 but 1.0 -> 1.0000

Comment: I updated to conform more to the OP @nettux443. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Python's standard lib's str.format() can be used to generate the string conversion of the float value.  Then the string can be manipulated to form a final result for either a positive or negative number.

```
n = -.1234567890
print('{0}'.format('-' if n < 0 else '') + ('{:0.4}'.format(n).split('-')[1 if n < 0 else 0].lstrip('0')))
```

Answer (score 1):

## For Python 3

When you want something simple and don't need negative number support:

```
f'{k:.4f}'.lstrip('0')
```

There are other solutions when you need negative number support, including the excellent regex by @nettux443.

Answer (score 0):

A super short (although not very pythonic) one-liner, which also handles negative numbers:

```
k = -.1337
"-"*(k<0)+("%.4f"%abs(k)).lstrip('0')
```

Comment: For the pythonic version of this line, see original answer by @John Haberstroh.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is to print a float without the leading zero, regardless of the sign of the float. The leading zero always precedes a decimal point. Split the printed float on '0.', and then rejoin the resulting list around just '.', as in below:

```
>> flt = -.31415926
```

-0.31415926

```
>> '%.4f' % flt    # prints leading zero
```

'-0.3142'

```
>> '.'.join( ('%.4f' % flt).split('0.'))    # removes leading zero
```

'-.3142'