# Decimal number parse in Python

Tags: python

I have a number as in below:

> .12

in my code I convert this number to string and parse it from the "point" to decimal as in below:

```
 mydecimal = str(mydecimal_new)
    whole_number = mydecimal.split('.')
    main_number = whole_number[0]
    #print(main_number)
    additional_number = whole_number[1]
    #print(additional_number)
```

My problem is when I try to convert this number to str python add 0 in front of the number and it keep the number as:

> 0.12

I want to know how can I avoid from the adding zero in front of this

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: how can I fly to the moon ?

Comment: contact NASA, ESA or RSA for basic training

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print floating point values without leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303797/print-floating-point-values-without-leading-zero)

Comment: @Michal thank you for the advice. I will keep in mind

Comment: print `re.sub("^0","",mydecimal)`

Comment: Thanks @downshift for your response this is actually correct response. However in my case it is little bit different entered number can be either .12 or 0.12 but because we said this number differently like "point twelve" and "o point twelve" this way will not work for me

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303797/print-floating-point-values-without-leading-zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
def _remove_leading_zero(value, string):
    if 1 > value > -1:
        string = string.replace('0', '', 1)
    return string


class MyFloat(float):
    def __str__(self):
        string = super().__str__()
        return _remove_leading_zero(self, string)

    def __format__(self, format_string):
        string = super().__format__(format_string)
        return _remove_leading_zero(self, string)


print(MyFloat(.12))
```

You Can Fly to the Moon Now :))) Good Luck.