# Matplotlib - Show floats as ".1" instead of "0.1" in tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is not a huge problem but I've got some subplots with a lot of important information to show in print later so I'd like it as clean as possible. I've got values between 0 and 1 in both axes and I'd like to ommit the 0 and show them as ".34", for example. Is it possible to do that without hardcode altering the labels?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the editor won't want the leading zeros? `0.34` is much easier to distinguish from `34` then `.34`.

Comment: There's no editor really, and all of the values I'm showing are between 0 and 1, so without the leading zeroes one can still understand that .34 is higher than .26 even if they read them as 34 and 26 and that's all I need.

Comment: [tick formatters](https://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) in the Matplotlib Gallery has examples of different format methods. I imagine one of the function or string formatters would work for you. ... https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=ticker

Comment: Related: [Print floating point values without leading zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303797/print-floating-point-values-without-leading-zero)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, .2, 10), np.linspace(0, .2, 10))
ax.set_yticklabels([str(x)[1:] for x in np.round(ax.get_yticks(), 3)])
plt.show()
```